# Controlling records with the same field value AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a table which name PaymentLines and i want to control dueDate field of records which have same InvoiceId value. If there is a different dueDate value, info -> Records with the same InvoiceId value cannot have different dueDate values

How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends when you want to control
for example if you want to do the control when you put the value in `DueDate` field overwrite `Modified` event of this field in datasource `PaymentLines`.

```
PaymentLines PaymentLinesCheck;

;

select PaymentLinesCheck where PaymentLinesCheck.InvoiceId == PaymentLines.InvoiceId &&
                               PaymentLinesCheck.DueDate != PaymentLines.DueDate;
if(PaymentLinesCheck)
{
    info("Records with the same InvoiceId value cannot have different dueDate values");
    //If you want to show an error message
    //error("Records with the same InvoiceId value cannot have different dueDate values");
    PaymentLines.DueDate = DateNull();        
}
```